# What assurances, if any, are given by the ELF linker for locating indirect dependencies?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, elf, rpath

Consider that I have an ELF shared library `liba.so`, which exports a symbol `from_a`. The implementation of `from_a` is defined in terms of a symbol `from_b`, which is exported from a shared library `libb.so`, and `liba.so` has a DT_NEEDED entry for `libb.so`.

I now have `program`, which uses the symbol `from_a`. When I link `program`, I include `-la` on the link line, along with whatever link-time search path, if any, is necessary for the linker to find `liba.so`. There are no direct dependencies on symbols from `libb.so` in `program`.

First question: is it guaranteed (in the sense of portable to all non-broken ELF using systems) that I do not need to list the indirect dependencies (in this case `libb.so`) of `liba.so` on the link line for `program`? I believe that this is true, but I would like to confirm. Is this behavior of the linker mandated by any specification? If so, which one (the ELF spec?)

Second question: If `liba.so` and `libb.so` are installed in a non-standard location (say $HOME/lib, as opposed to /usr/lib) that is not default searched, then when linking `program`, the BFD linker, at least on my current system and a few others I've tested, will complain that `libb.so` cannot be found, despite the fact that the library install directory is specified with -L, and suggests using `-rpath` or `-rpath-link`. However, if an RPATH or RUNPATH identifying the install location is set in `liba.so`, then the BFD linker is placated. Why does the BFD linker care about whether or not `libb.so` can be found at link time, if `program` has no direct dependency on it? Is the behavior obtained by setting RPATH on `liba.so` guaranteed? It would be nice to rely on this to placate the linker. I have also noticed that the gold linker does *not* fail in this case. What is the intended behavior here?

Comment: Well, for historical reasons, I'll note that I've written a test for this behavior. It appears to work in Lucid, Precise, and Raring. You can obtain a copy of the test here: https://github.com/acmorrow/solib-rpath-test. I hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the test mentioned above, this appears to work on all recent versions of Ubuntu. If you are interested in this question, and use my test, and find a platform where this behavior does not work, please reply in the comments.